# How to mock an instance variable using Mockito in java?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm a noob to unit testing and use of mockito

I have a class

```
public class SystemTenancyConfig {
    private String systemTenancy;
}
```

I have used this in another class where I'm getting the value:

```
@Inject
SystemTenancyConfig systemTenancyConfig;
String val = systemTenancyConfig.getsystemTenancy();
```

How do I mock systemTenancyConfig.getsystemTenancy() to be set to a string say "Test"?
UpdatE:

```
    @Mock
    private SystemTenancyConfig systemTenancyConfig;
       when(systemTenancyConfig.getSystemTenancy()).thenReturn("test");
```

is giving me a NPE

Comment: How do you create the instance of "another class"? How is the mock of SystemTenancyConfig provided?

Answer (score 1):

the condition when getsystemTenancy will trigger your mock

```
when(systemTenancy.getsystemTenancy()).thenReturn(what you want it return);
    systemTenancy.getsystemTenancy()
```

also @Mock over the Object you want to mock the whole Object

example

```
@Inject
private SystemTenancyConfig systemTenancyConfig;

@Test
function void testingSomething(){
   when(systemTenancyConfig.getSystemTenancy()).thenReturn("test"); // condition to trigger the mock and return test
   String val = systemTenancyConfig.getsystemTenancy();
}
```

Comment: ` @Mock
    private SystemTenancyConfig systemTenancyConfig;`  and         when(systemTenancyConfig.getSystemTenancy()).thenReturn("test");
is giving me NPE

Comment: @Mock use only if you intent to mock the whole object in your case just when(systemTenancyConfig.getSystemTenancy()).thenReturn("test"); should be enough and it should be declare before that method get call

Comment: @Mock will put your object into null like it have never been declare in case you want to mock the whole thing without his behavior similar to SystemTenancyConfig systemTenancyConfig = null;